# Loading libraries in head tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So my challenge is to make two different GUI-elements in the same document, each requiring a seperate library. One of them needs the traditional JQuery-ui library, the other wants a link to this:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

I've basically fought a war to make them both work, and I did in the end by putting the above code right between the loading of JQuery and Jquery-ui-libraries. If I put it before, then I couldn't call the methods in its library. If I put it after, then I couldn't call the methods in the JQuery-ui library. Can someone explain this to me?

Here is my working head tag:

```
<head>
    <title>Experimentation</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylingExp.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
```

Comment: select the version of jQuery tools that doesn't include jQuery.

Comment: Thanks you a lot Kevin B!! Everything works like a charm when I only load the JQuery tools and JQuery-ui =]

Answer (score 0):

its dependent on jquery, so if you call it before jquery has loaded it wont work.  The jquery library has be loaded so it can call it

Comment: Alright. What if I call it after both JQuery and Jquery-ui has loaded then. Why doesn't JQuery-ui work?